# How to, using Apache FOP, print element depending on free space?

Tags: styles, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Using Apache-FOP, I'm building a PDF report that is built by several fo:blocks and they together usually uses 5-6 pages. But, if there is a free space left, I'd like to add optional messages.

The important condition for these additional messages is that they cannot make the report expand for another page.

So the code looks like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <fo:root>
    ...
    <fo:block>something important 1</fo:block>
    <fo:block>optional message 1a</fo:block>
    <fo:block>something important 2</fo:block>
    <fo:block>optional message 2a</fo:block>
    <fo:block>optional message 2b</fo:block>
    <fo:block>something important 3</fo:block>
    ...
  </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

Now I'd like to print block "1a" only if blocks 1, 2, 3 takes as much pages as blocks 1, 1a, 2, 3. Then check for block 2a, and then block 2b.

Any help would be appreciate, even a pointer to the attributes/styles I should check.

The only way I found so far was to build an report without optional message and the second with such and compare if there was an increase in page count, but this is not an option to go.

Comment: I wrote this long ago and it references RenderX http://www.renderx.com/solutions/wp_transpromo.html you can try to adopt similar methods using Apache FOP as it has a similar area tree representation. Your sample would be made a bit more complicated as one would be required to format also the optional messages and "measure" them for inclusion. We have similar implementations using RenderX running two formatters and including area tree from one in the other.

Comment: Personally, I would not count on adapting from RenderX to FOP, they are built on the same technologies but the differences between them are not always trivial, their custom namespace and functions can sometimes hard to translate to FOP (although it's not impossible, RenderX is just more fully featured and can do complex tasks while making them look simple) Can you give a simple example of what your PDF would ideally look like? Might be able to give you some direction if I have an idea of what your trying to achieve ultimately. I have a feeling your over complicating things for yourself.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot share actual code, as it is customer property and customer requirements to fill the blank leftovers with messages.

Comment: Is it a problem for your customers if some of the optional message might be cut off? You could set the overflow property to hidden and disable text-wrap, in that case and you could at least ensure that the optional message can take up no more than one line in the document. Also, are you looking to interleave the required content with the optional content if it fits, or are you just writing out these messages at the end of the document in the space left over?